# How do I make an event in google calander repeat everyday except every 4th day?

Tags: google-calendar, events

My workout routine is 3 days of exercise then a rest day, so I can't just make it every Monday or whatever, I want a few events that I normally do after my workout to be moved back 20 mins

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.